# I am working on a basic toDo app. When I long press on the item it should be deleted from my list but it does nothing. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add and delete items in my todo list. It adds the items fine but I have set up a onLongClickListener for deleting the items and it does nothing. I am a beginner so I may have missed something. Please help me out. Any help is appreciated.

```
 package com.example.todolist;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.os.Build;
  import android.app.ListActivity;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private ArrayList<String> items; 
private ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
private EditText ptadd;
private Button badd;
private ListView lvTodo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
    items = new ArrayList <String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,adroid.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    lvTodo.setAdapter(adapter);
            setListViewListener();


}   
private void setListViewListener(){
    lvTodo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener (){

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> vadapter, View item,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            items.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

    });;
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ptadd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etadd);
    lvTodo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTodo);
    badd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);
    badd.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String lv = ptadd.getText().toString();
    adapter.add(lv);
    ptadd.setText("");

}
```

}

my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"

 >
 <ListView
       android:id="@+id/lvTodo"
       android:layout_width="293sp"
       android:layout_height="250sp" >

</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etadd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:ems="10"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/badd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Add"

     />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is onItemLongClick getting called?

Comment: Where you call `setListViewListener()` method?

Comment: Maybe your ArrayList `item` is `null`. Check it to find if this is populated as well. - Note: this import `android.app.ListActivity` is useless in your case.

Comment: Just tested your code on my device. It works! Items are deleted... I pasted it as it is, without changes. You just have a typo here adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, aNdroid.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items) (missed "n")

Comment: Hi PriyaKar, if [Quinnjn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23281285/2668136) resolved your issue, please consider [accepting it by clicking the check-mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/253846). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, you're never calling `setListViewListener`. Call the method in `initialize`

```
private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ptadd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etadd);
    lvTodo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTodo);
    badd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);
    badd.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Missing this
    setListViewListener();
}
```

Comment: @nasch Oh sorry.. I did add this and even so it does not seem to work. :(

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. But i tried after adding it as well.

Comment: @Fllo if that was the case then would the items still show up in the list?

Comment: @PriyaKar normally no. However, I don't see in your code where your arraylist is populated..

Comment: @Fllo I am doing it in the OnClick method. I can see the items added but it just does not delete them

Comment: @Onik Thank you so much..!! I tried running it and it did work after correcting it.! Thank you again.. :)